# Entertainment-related compounds

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I just want to ask and confirm a few compounds.

1. **games shop** or **game shop** - a place where you can buy video games
2. **amusement arcade** or **arcade** - a place where people went to play arcade machines in the 80s and 90s. Are they called **arcade machines**?
3. Is there a singular word to call all things in a casino? I mean slot machines, wheels of fortune and so on. **Machines** maybe?

Comment: In my opinion, it's kind of late in the day (eight years late, in fact) to be asking the poster to show research related to the posted question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much dead on with all of these.

Keep in mind however, that in some cases "Game shop" is used to refer to a store that sells board or tabletop games, rather than electronic ones; however, either usage is understood to be accurate.

Generally, Arcade is used on it's own in the modern era, though "amusement arcade" is more technically accurate and understood. And yes, "Arcade machines" or "Arcade cabinets", depending on who you ask would describe the devices inside.

And yeah, collectively, the various electronic and mechanical games in a Casino are often simply referred to as "Machines" when describing them collectively. (Or even individually, as 'the machine' if you're looking to be vague for some reason.)

Comment: then video game shop should do the job?